# Clients commands processed by the server C

Tags: c++, winapi, client-server, named-pipes

I'm building a Server/Client chat application in a Win32 (C++) environment, using named pipes, and i'm struggling to find a better solution on how to process the commands requested by the clients(not the concurrency problems nor synchronize). The only solution that i can come up with is this one:

Imagine that the client can only send a few commands to the server, like:

```
-> Logon arg1 arg2
-> Register arg1 arg2
-> Chat_info 
-> Exit
```

Now, on the server side the information must be processed but how can he catch the arguments?

What i'm trying to accomplish is an interaction with the server and not a simple echo response from him, for example: as a client i would send: Logon Ricardo pass123
 and the server would check if that username and password are valid.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe something like `std::map<std::string, std::function<...>>`? Hard to say since it isn't very clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So the server would read the first "string" and in function of that would call a function using the rest of the arguments previously passed?

Comment: It would probably be more useful to tell us what you want to accomplish instead of pseudo-code for a possible solution to a problem we don't know or understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly i've find a better solution for my problem. Here it is:

Server.c

```
while(1){
//...
printf("[SERVER] Waiting for a client... (ConnectNamedPipe)\n");
    if(!ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL)){
        perror("Connection Error!");
        //exit(-1);
    }
    CreateThread(NULL,0,ListenClient,(LPVOID)hPipe,0,NULL);
}
```

Everytime that a client gets his named pipe created, gets aswell a new Thread and in the "ListenClient" function:

```
DWORD WINAPI ListenClient(LPVOID param) { ... }
```

which will read the information passed through the pipe like:

```
ret = ReadFile(hPipe, buf, 256,(LPDWORD) &n, NULL);
if (!ret || !n)
    perror("Error reading the named pipe!");
buf[n] = '\0';
```

there will be as many conditions as the options that each client can request from the server, like:

```
if(strcmp(buf, "Logon")==0)
{
 //process the resquest
}


if(strcmp(buf, "Register")==0)
{
 //process the request
}

and so on..
```

This way the server will read from the buffer and do a simple string compare on the first argument sent.

Thank you all and i hope it helps someone!